# Excel data from database - refresh only part of it

Tags: excel, pivot, refresh

I have a big table in a database, containing information for many years. It is transferred to MS Excel via ODBC / Microsoft query and used in a pivot table.

The data refresh in Excel is taking a lot of time. But 99% of the info is not changing, so I need to refresh only the 1% that is changed. Do you know whether it is possible?

Comment: Do you have a way of knowing what the 1% of data is that will be changing before you issue the query?

Comment: Yes, this is only the info for the current date. The problem is how to refresh only this info?

Comment: Split the query up in two, one for all data before today and one for all data after. You can use separate sheets for this. Then create a pivot table that [consolidates these two into one](http://www.contextures.com/xlPivot08.html). Assuming most of the time is taken up by refreshing the data and not by the pivot table itself, this should speed things up considerably.

Comment: Hello Jeroen, thank you for your suggestion, it works, I want to mark it as a correct answer but how to do it, since it is a comment only? May be you can post it as an answer?